# Issue on Using each() in jQuery Radio Option State Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio option like

```
 <input type="radio" name="options" value="yes" />Yes<br />
 <input type="radio" name="options" value="no" />No<br />
```

and I have a jquery like below to get the state of options. now my question is while the `var val = $('input:radio[name=options]:checked').attr('value');` is returning the acquired value of selected radio, do I really need to use `each()` like what I have in second snippet?

```
    var val = '';
    $.each($('input:radio[name=options]:checked'), function() {
        val += $(this).attr('value');
    });
```

and here are the codes

```
$('input:radio[name=options]').on('change', function() {
    var val = $('input:radio[name=options]:checked').attr('value');
    switch (val) {
        case 'yes':
            disturbance = false;
            console.log(disturbance);
            break;
        case 'no':
            disturbance = true;
            console.log(disturbance);
            break;
        }
});
```

and

```
$('input:radio[name=options]').on('change', function() {
    var val = '';
    $.each($('input:radio[name=options]:checked'), function() {
        val += $(this).attr('value');
    });
    switch (val) {
        case 'yes':
            disturbance = false;
            console.log(disturbance);
            break;
        case 'no':
            disturbance = true;
            console.log(disturbance);
            break;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, as your selector `$('input:radio[name="options"]')` has already specified the `name` property, and radio is grouped by `name`, there will be only 1 radio in the same group selected at the same time, so you don't need to iterate through them.

And from [MDN.event.change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)'s description about when change event will be fire from `radio`:

> When the element is activated (by clicking or using the keyboard) for
>   `<input type="radio">` and `<input type="checkbox">`;

The event will only be fired from the one you selected.

Also, you can just use `.val()` to get the value from the input.

Unless you're using `checkbox`, then you have to iterate through the selected checkboxes to get the values. Because when you use `.val()`, you'll only get the first input's value. See the description from [jQuery#.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), [jQuery#.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), Both of the function has similar description:

> Get the  (value of an attribute | current value) of the first element in the set of matched elements or ....

But checkbox can have multiple selected in the same name group, so you need to iterate through all `checked` checkboxes to get all of their value.

```js
$('input:radio[name="options"]').on('change', function() {
    var val = $('input:radio[name=options]:checked').val();
    switch (val) {
        case 'yes':
            disturbance = false;
            console.log(disturbance);
            break;
        case 'no':
            disturbance = true;
            console.log(disturbance);
            break;
        }
});

$('input:checkbox[name="fruit"]').on('change', function() {
    // It'll only get val from first checked checkbox, ignore others
    var val = $('input:checkbox[name=fruit]:checked').val();
    console.log(val);
    var result = [];
    $.each($('input:checkbox[name=fruit]:checked'), function(idx, item) {
        result.push($(item).val());
    });
    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="yes" />Yes<br />
 <input type="radio" name="options" value="no" />No<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple" />Apple<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Banana" />Banana<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Orange" />Orange<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks fuyushimoya, it was a very perfect explanation. but in `checkbox` , can you please let me know why it needs to use the `each()` method?

Comment: I've add a situation on checbox, you can take a look now.